# Listing PrincipleIDs eligible for Global Admin role with Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I know that this will give me active role assignments

$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10/members"
$Role = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header -Method get -ContentType "application/json"
$Role.value.displayname

but how do I get eligible role assignments? the only thing I can find is requests to PIM-up but nothing that shows me what users have the ability to PIM-up for a specific role.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the API to get the List the directory roles that are activated in the tenant

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles
```

This operation only returns roles that have been activated. A role becomes activated when an admin activates the role using the Activate directoryRole API. Not all built-in roles are initially activated.

When assigning a role using the Azure portal, the role activation step is implicitly done on the admin's behalf. To get the full list of roles that are available in Azure AD, use List directoryRoleTemplates.

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example

Answer (score 0):

Graph API has Privileged Identity Management API. I'm not familiar with this API but you can retrieve the requests for role eligibilities for principals:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-roleeligibilityschedulerequests?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Documentation

[Privileged Identity Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/privilegedidentitymanagementv3-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)